# Perl 5.8: possible to get any return code from backticks when SIGCHLD in use

Tags: linux, perl

When a CHLD signal handler is used in Perl, even uses of system and backticks will send the CHLD signal. But for the system and backticks sub-processes, neither wait nor waitpid seem to set $? within the signal handler on SuSE 11 linux. Is there **any** way to determine the return code of a backtick command when a CHLD signal handler is active?

Why do I want this? Because I want to fork(?) and start a medium length command and then call a perl package that takes a long time to produce an answer (and which executes external commands with backticks and checks their return code in $?), and know when my command is finished so I can take action, such as starting a second command. (Suggestions for how to accomplish this without using SIGCHLD are also welcome.) But since the signal handler destroys the backtick $? value, that package fails.

Example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

sub reaper {
    my $signame = shift @_;
    while (1) {
       my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
       last if $pid <= 0;
       my $rc = $?;
       print "wait()=$pid, rc=$rc\n";
    }
}

$SIG{CHLD} = \&reaper;

# system can be made to work by not using $?, instead using system return value
my $rc = system("echo hello 1");
print "hello \$?=$?\n";
print "hello rc=$rc\n";

# But backticks, for when you need the output, cannot be made to work??
my @IO = `echo hello 2`;
print "hello \$?=$?\n";

exit 0;
```

Yields a -1 return code in all places I might try to access it:

```
hello 1
wait()=-1, rc=-1
hello $?=-1
hello rc=0
wait()=-1, rc=-1
hello $?=-1
```

So I cannot find anywhere to access the backticks return value.

Comment: Backticks waits for its child to exit. You should put your SIGCHLD handler on hold during the backticks.

Comment: if I completely turn off the CHLD handler around the backticks (which is actually a separate package), then I might not get the signal if the child ends when it is disabled.

Comment: You'll get it when you unmask it. Or if not, you can just call your signal handler unconditionally when you unmask it.

Comment: Another solution is to run the code you currently run in the parent inside another child.

Comment: thank you, I think I will pursue the double fork suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same issue has been bugging me for a few days now. I believe there are 2 solutions required depending on where you have your backticks.

**If you have your backticks inside the child code:**

The solution was to put the line below inside the child fork. I think your statement above "if I completely turn off the CHLD handler around the backticks then I might not get the signal if the child ends" is incorrect. You will still get a callback in the parent when the child exits because the signal is only disabled inside the child. So the parent still gets a signal when the child exits. It's just the child doesn't get a signal when the child's child (the part in backticks) exits.

`local $SIG{'CHLD'} = 'DEFAULT'`

I'm no Perl expert, I have read that you should set the CHLD signal to the string 'IGNORE' but this did not work in my case. In face I believe it may have been causing the problem. Leaving that out completely appears to also solve the problem which I guess is the same as setting it to DEFAULT.

**If you have backticks inside the parent code:**

Add this line to your reaper function:
`local ($!, $?);`

What is happening is the reaper is being called when your code inside the backticks completes and the reaper is setting $?. By making $? local it does not set the global $?.

Comment: Note that it is $SIG{CHLD}, not $sig{CHLD}, and $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer and also changed it to DEFAULT as I believe that is the same as setting it to undef but undef does not appear to work in 5.8

Answer (score 0):

So, building on MikeKull's answer, here is a working example where the fork'd child uses backticks and still gets the proper return code. This example is a better representation of what I was doing, while the original example did not use forks and could not convey the entire issue.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

# simple child which returns code 5
open F, ">", "exit5.sh" or die "$!";
print F<<EOF;
#!/bin/bash
echo exit5 pid=\$\$
exit 5
EOF
close F;

sub reaper
{
    my $signame = shift @_;
    while (1)
    {
        my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
        print "no child waiting\n" if $pid < 0;
        last if $pid <= 0;
        my $rc = $? >> 8;
        print "wait()=$pid, rc=$rc\n";
    }
}

$SIG{CHLD} = \&reaper;

if (!fork)
{
    print "child pid=$$\n";
  { local $SIG{CHLD} = 'DEFAULT'; print `./exit5.sh`; }
    print "\$?=" . ($? >> 8) . "\n";
    exit 3;
}

# sig CHLD will interrupt sleep, so do multiple
sleep 2;sleep 2;sleep 2;

exit 0;
```

The output is:

```
child pid=32307
exit5 pid=32308
$?=5
wait()=32307, rc=3
no child waiting
```

So the expected return code 5 was received in the child when the parent's reaper was disabled before calling the child, but as indicated by ikegami the parent still gets the CHLD signal and a proper return code when the child exits.